# Probability for two events

Tags: probability

If probability of $A$ is $0.5$ and that of $A$ intersection $B$ is $0.2$. Then find the probability of $A$ complement union $B$.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Whenever you post your query here, please post along with your work.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $A^c\cup B=(A\cap B^c)^c=(A\backslash B)^c=(A\backslash(A\cap B))^c$. You are given $P(A)$ and $P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $A\supseteq B$, then
$$
P(A\setminus B)=P(A)-P(B).
$$